# Counterexample of almost everywhere convergence implies convergence in measure.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I know when $\mu(E)<\infty$ then almost everywhere convergence implies convergence in measure. But what if $\mu(E)=\infty$? Is there a counterexample that shows almost everywhere convergence does not imply convergence in measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the typical example is to consider, on $\mathbb R$, the sequence $f_n=1_{[n,\infty)}$. Then $f_n\to0$ pointwise (everywhere!), but
$$
m(|f_n|>\varepsilon)=\infty
$$
for all $\varepsilon>0$.